# How Do I put a javascript time delay in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, html5-canvas

I am working on an animation using Javascript and HTML5 CAnvas. How do achieve a delay ( non-blocking ) within a for loop ? I want to make sure that the second line doesnt get drawn before the delay is over .

```
for (i=1;i<coor.length;i++)

        {
            context.beginPath();
            var end_point=coor[i];
            var x1y1=start_point.split(',');
            var x2y2= end_point.split(',');


            context.moveTo(parseInt(x1y1[0]),parseInt(x1y1[1]));
            context.lineTo(parseInt(x2y2[0]),parseInt(x2y2[1]));
            context.stroke();

            start_point=end_point;


        }
```

Comment: Added actual code . HTML5 canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you could re-factor your code:

```
function animate(position)
{
   // do stuff based on position

   if(position++ < 100){
       setTimeout(function(){animate(position);}, 100);
   }
}
```

Comment: I did this . Works like magic .. Perfect . Thanks for the timely help :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery, check out the [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) API.

```
el.delay(800).fadeIn(400);
```

inside the for-loop, assuming `el` is a jQuery object outside the for loop.

Otherwise, I'd just use `setTimeout(function(){ ... }, i * 100);`

Comment: @Peter yeah, okay so .delay() actually wouldn't do what one wants -- I was hoping/assuming that there would be an arbitrary callback that one could chain, but it actually looks like there isn't.  I'll leave the jQuery bit in so your comment makes sense :P

Answer (score 1):

This code will create delay of 2 seconds.

```
var i=0;    
setInterval(function () {
    context.beginPath();
                var end_point=coor[i];
                var x1y1=start_point.split(',');
                var x2y2= end_point.split(',');


                context.moveTo(parseInt(x1y1[0]),parseInt(x1y1[1]));
                context.lineTo(parseInt(x2y2[0]),parseInt(x2y2[1]));
                context.stroke();
                i++;
                start_point=end_point;

    }, 2000);
```

Through this code you can omit `FOR` loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a blocking sleep call, JavaScript doesn't have native support for that.

if however you are simply looking to execute a piece of code at a fixed interval, you can use

- [`[intervalHandle] setInterval(<callback>, <ms>)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval)
- [`[void] clearInterval(<intervalHandle>)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval).

The `<callback>` can be any function, anonymous or named.

If you're planning to use it for animation, you ought to look into [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame)
as a superior alternative